# Objects of custom classes as Nodes and Relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I recently started to explore graph DB's, and I've decided to work more with neo4j. I understand that the nodes and edges in neo4j DB are arbitrary, and that one or more properties (key-value pairs, where the values must be of primitive types only) can be assigned to the nodes and relationships.

Is there a way to make objects of my own classes as NODES and EDGES, so that the proprties of the nodes and edges are encapsulated in the objects themselves?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  The answer below solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean a way of object-graph mapping?

You could look into [Spring Data Neo4j](http://springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j) or other mapping approaches like [jo4neo](http://code.google.com/p/jo4neo/) or [TinkerPop Frames](https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames).

an Example from Spring Data Neo4j

```
@NodeEntity class Person {
   @GraphId Long id;
   String name;

   Person spouse;
   @RelatedTo
   Set<Person> friends;

   @Query("start me = node({self}) match me-[:friends]->friends-[:friends]->foaf return foaf")
   Set<Person> friendsOfFriends;
}
```